# How do I see which UAC permission was requested?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, uac

Is there the a way to view the permissions required when User Account Control dialog box pops up?

I have this executable file that has a UAC icon on its lower left of its icon. I assume that it requires administrator privileges before it can run. Is there a way I can see the permission it needs so I can further assess whether I will run the program or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a program requests elevation, it requests every admin permission and to be granted the (second, technically) highest set of permissions. It doesn't request a specific permission, and once granted admin it can do anything it wants with those powers.